# Angle of reflection relative to coordinate system

Tags: python, vector, reflection, geometry, simulation

I have a two 2D points `u = (ux, uy)` and `v = (vx, vy)` that define a line segment.
Additionally I have an angle `θ` that is defined relative to the coordinate system (angle to x-axis), indicating the directing of a moving particle.
Is there a simple way to find the angle of reflection resulting (again, relative to the coordinate system) from that particle bouncing off the line segment?

So far I have found the angle of the line segment `θuv = numpy.arctan2(vy-uy, vx-ux)`, taken the difference `Δθ = θuv - θ` and set the resulting angle to `θ_reflected = θ - 2*Δθ`.
Sometimes, this seems to work, but other times it's completely off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segment has length

```
leng = hypot(vy-uy, vx-ux)
```

and unit direction vector  (perhaps in numpy there is ready function like `normalized`)

```
dx = (vx-ux) / leng
dy = (vy-uy) / leng
```

Unit normal to segment

```
nx = - dy
ny = dx
```

particle direction vector is

```
px = cos(θ)
py = sin(θ)
```

Reflected vector

```
dott = dot(p, n) = px * nx + py * ny
rx = px - 2 * dott * nx
ry = py - 2 * dott * ny
```

If you need angle

```
θ_reflected = atan2(ry, rx)
```

but sometimes particle direction vector components are more useful